# Next.js api route resolving to 404 BUT it works fine via postman

Tags: next.js

Please see the attachment, it shows the folder structure, and the "404" error I am getting when I try to fetch the api. When I run the same api via postman it works fine. But within the nextjs ecosystem, I get a 404. Is there a config issue perhaps I am missing.

[image]

Comment: are you getting this error when running `next build`?

Answer (score 2):

From the doc https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

> Note: You should not use fetch() to call an API route in getServerSideProps. Instead, directly import the logic used inside your API route. You may need to slightly refactor your code for this approach.
> Fetching from an external API is fine!